# Why are O-antigens and H-antigens on (certain) bacteria called O and H?

Tags: bacteriology, terminology, antigen, bacterial-toxins

Somehow, despite extensive searching, I cannot find an answer....

Does O stand for oxygen and H signify hydrogen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "H" and "O" identifiers first appeared in German-language publications around 1920 to describe different forms of disease-causing bacilli. Thankfully, Arkwright and Goyle provide an English explanation of the terms in their 1924 review.<sup>**1**</sup>

> These writers called the two forms, which they described, the "H" and the "O" form, because in the case of *B. proteus*, the first bacillus investigated, the "H" form was represented by the normal, which grew with a spreading film (***Hauch***) on the surface of agar, whilst the "O" form, which occurred as a variant, grew in isolated colonies without any film (***ohne Hauch***).

The literal translation of *Hauch* is "breath", and *ohne Hauch* is "without breath", though [some sources](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-german/thin-layer) translate *Hauch* as "thin layer", which is probably the intended meaning.

---

**References**

1. Arkwright JA, Goyle AN. The Relation of the “Smooth” and “Rough” Forms of Intestinal Bacteria to the “O” and “H” Forms of Weil and Felix. *Br J Exp Pathol.* 1924;5(2):104-114.

Comment: As a German speaker, "Hauch" idiomatically means something like "a touch of ...", so "thin layer" is indeed an appropriate translation in this context.